# How to implement non-zero count constraint for cvxpy in integer programming

Tags: cvxpy, integer-programming

I want to implement the constraint that the number of non-zero elements per row in x is less than 2.

```py
constraint2 = cp.sum( x >= 0, 1) <= 2
```

but get the error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Inequality'
what to do ?

I had try `constraint2.append(cp.log(cp.sum(cp.pos(-(x[i, :] - epsilon)) / epsilon)) >= 13)` but get `cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:`. What should I do?

Comment: You have to make an explicit mixed-integer model with binary variables, big-M constraints and the cardinality bound. See for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#integer-modeling Details depend on what are the original bounds for ``x``, for instance is it always nonnegative or general real. There is no simple syntactic sugar in cvxpy/python to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much,

```python
x = cp.Variable((m, n), integer=True)
z0 = cp.Variable((m, n), boolean=True)
for i in range(m):
    constraint2.append(x[i, :] <= max_ele * z0[i, :])
    constraint2.append(cp.sum(z0[i, :]) <= 2)
```

could you please this can solve my issue?